# SQL query with typical properties table

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking for help on building SQL query:

I have two tables:

Table1 - Object:

```
object_id    name       owner
1           Object1    Owner1
2           Object2    Owner2
3           Object3    Owner3
```

Table2 - Object Properties (each Object has exactly 3 properties)

```
object_id         property_name       Property_value
    1                   color              blue
    1                   shape              circle
    1                   inhouse            true
    2                   color              red
    2                   shape              rectangle
    2                   inhouse            false
    3                   color              green
    3                   shape              rectangle
    3                   inhouse            true
```

I would like to build a view like this:

```
name       owner      color       shape       inhouse
Object1    Owner1     blue       circle       true
Object2    Owner2     red        rectangle    false
Object3    Owner3     green      rectangle    true
```

Comment: Did you try a query?

Comment: The term you'll want to search is 'pivot'...there are usually 2-3 of these questions asked per day, so you should be able to find one matching your question very readily with a search of Stackoverflow.  Give an attempt and if you are still having issues, post up the code you've tried and we'll help.  Otherwise, this isn't a free code writing service website